# Merging zipcodes based on population to create larger areas in QGIS

Tags: qgis, merge, features, polygon-creation, aggregation

In QGIS I have a shapefile with small geographic areas (zipcodes) with population in each zipcode area. Currently the population per zipcode vary very much, some as low as 1 person living in them. I would like to merge adjacent zipcodes with low population values to produce a more homogenous population areas.

In pseudo code terms I would like to:

1. Given a zipcode, merge it with adjacent zipcodes until total
   population is at least 200.
2. Redo step 1 until I have a shapefile with new features (aggregated
   zipcodes) that have a population of at least 200.

So far the only way I found to do this is manually looking up zipcodes and merging them, but since the shapefile contains many thousand zipcodes it quickly becomes infeasible.

Comment: Do you have any programming/scripting experience? What API(s) do you have available? So long as you aren't too fussy about which polygons get merged an iterative buffer selection should work.

Comment: I have some experience in programming in python, but have not written scripts for QGIS. At this stage, I'm not too concerned about which polygons get merged as long as total population stays over a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

I found a script online from University of Southampton that does exactly what I was looking for. It can be downloaded here: http://aztool.geodata.soton.ac.uk/

> AZTool is a software program for automated zone design, developed by
> Prof David Martin, Dr Samantha Cockings, Andrew Harfoot and various
> colleagues in the School of Geography and Environmental Science at the
> University of Southampton. It takes a set of geographical zones
> (usually termed "building blocks") and iteratively aggregates them
> into a number of larger zones (“tracts”), optimised to meet
> user-specified design criteria. The software is written in VB.NET
> using the .NET framework version 2. No Geographical Information System
> (GIS) software is required to run AZTool, but GIS will assist in data
> preparation and visualisation of the results.